# How to setup email server for my Tor Hidden Service?

Tags: configuration, email

I'm wanting to setup an SMTP server for my tor hidden service. I'm assuming doing so would be as simple as setting up a normal email server and just giving its domain name as the hostname for however I've configured the second hidden service, but I haven't been able to find much information online to do with hosting two separate hidden services on the same server and I'm unsure as how to exactly go about setting up a 2nd hidden service on the server I'm already hosting one on. I've noticed that in the /etc/tor/torrc file, it mentions /var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/ but looking in my own /var/lib/tor/ directory, there doesn't seem to be any other directories there to do with other hidden services.

Do I need to somehow setup an /var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/ directory? If so, how? Or would it be possible for me to host the email server using the same hostname I already have setup for my onion site?

Comment: please post your `torrc` config - let's take a look! I used to set up QMail working just fine with Tor

Answer (score 0):

> I've noticed that in the /etc/tor/torrc file, it mentions
> /var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/ but looking in my own /var/lib/tor/
> directory, there doesn't seem to be any other directories there to do
> with other hidden services.

Create a new directory called "/var/lib/tor/mailserver/" and add it to your torrc. Make very sure that your file permissions are the same as the original directory or else Tor won't be able to write to it and it will fail.

Comment: Do I need to give this new directory keys and a hostname like the other one? Or is that sorted out automatically by adding the directory to the torrc file?

Comment: It should be automatically generated as long as the permissions are correct.

Comment: They had the same permissions, debian-tor, but the owner of my new email_server_hidden_service/ directory was root. Upon changing the owner of my new email_server_hidden_service/ directory to debian-tor like the rest of the folders in that directory and restarting the tor service, the email_server_hidden_service/ directory was still empty. No keys, no hostname, nothing.